# Javascript Not Working in HTML - In a Variety of Ways

Tags: javascript, html, include, xampp

Is it possible to load javascript without jQuery?  I spent the better portion of yesterday evening simply trying to create the most basic HTML page with working CSS and Javascript and - despite the numerous methods I have tried - none of them have worked.  Here is my basic HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>On</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click Me!">
  </body>
</html>
```

This is being hosted locally on XAMPP, the page displays fine and the CSS works fine, the javascript is in the same directory as the html page and works fine when written inline with the HTML.  However the js does not work in *any* of the following scenarios when trying to include it as an externality:

When `application/javascript` is used above it still doesn't work.  All I receive in either case (in the Firebug script window) is "popup()" and that's it.  Here is the script.js file:

```
function popup() {
  alert("Hello World")
}
```

This js also doesn't work (I tried it even though I'm not parsing XML):

```
//<![CDATA[
function popup() {
  alert("Hello World")
}
//]]>
```

nor this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function popup() {
  alert("Hello World")
})
```

nor this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() {
  alert("Hello World")
}
</script>
```

Not that I really expected it too, but I was getting desperate.  If anyone knows what's going on, I'd appreciate any info.

I'm open to this being an issue with hosting this locally on XAMMP but find it doubtful as CSS and HTML are both flying.  However the js works if I include it inline with the HTML(?).  If it helps, when Firebug displays popup() in the script window it also shows an @conn1source connection.

UPDATE: according to one of the suggestions in the comments if I only write the following in the js file it works:

```
alert("Hello World")
```

however the function does not.  So I'm guessing this means that I wrapped the function somehow incorrectly in the js file, but I'm following standard practice as far as I am aware.

Comment: you definitely dont need jquery for this- are you sure you are referencing the ```script.js``` file correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've checked many times.  The call is <script src="script.js" type="application/javascript"></script> and the directory structure is simply the script.js. style.css, and html file all in the same directory.  Really simple and straightforward, or so it seemed.

Comment: `type="text/javasvcript"` -> note the typo. It's `"text/javascript"`. Your browser doesn't understand that it's javascript because you misspelled it, hence the script isn't included at all (properly).

Comment: Is your "script.js" file in the same folder as the HTML file you're serving up?  If you put a `console.log("Hi");` at the top of your script file does this appear in the console when you open the page?  And the `type` property on script tags is [unnecessary](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-script-type) anyway.

Comment: Thank you, but the typo was a variant added by me today apparently.  It is not working ala correctly spelled "javascript".

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your developer tools. Is the script loading correctly? Look in the Console of your developer tools. What do they say when you click the button?

Comment: You don't need the type btw, <script></script> is enough.

And don't forget the ; at the end of each instructions.

Comment: Remove the type at all. Write just `alert('test');` inside `script.js`. Run it and see what's happening. Check debugger!

Comment: @Alex "Hi" does not appear in the console.  As I've already stated the js file is in the same directory as the html.

Comment: "Is the script loading correctly?" — further to that: Is there an attempt to load it at all? If so, does it give a 200 OK response?

Comment: @Andrey...hmmmm...alert('test') actually works.  So is it how I'm wrapping the function in the js?  Weird.

Comment: I'm going to edit the post and mention that alert('test') actually works.

Comment: Really simple - rename the function to something weird, like `myTestFunction`. Then simply use `<body onload='myTestFunction'>` If it alerts - you're ready to go - just fix the button. If not - then you are insane :D

Comment: No, however I rebooted Firefox and it proceeded to work.  I did have some multiple conn01source threads apparently open, I have no idea if that was somehow clogging up anything or why they were maintained after various page reloads.  Firebug was also consistently loading the js and listing it as not loaded before I rebooted.  Maybe the bug is in Firebug, which I am now going to look into.  Thank you everyone for your help.